# Add Webpack Importer to Vue CLI Project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I'm currently trying to use [node-sass-json-importer](https://github.com/Updater/node-sass-json-importer) in a Vue CLI project. This would allow me to share values for colors between my JavaScript and SCSS styles:

`style-vars.json`

```
{  "bgColor": "red"  }
```

`component.vue`

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import './style-vars.json';
  body { color: $bgColor; }
</style>
```

I've tried adding this importer to `build/utils.js` as an importer by modifying this block:

```
  // Top of file
  var jsonImporter = require('node-sass-json-importer')

  // ...
  return {
    css: generateLoaders(),
    postcss: generateLoaders(),
    less: generateLoaders('less'),
    sass: generateLoaders('sass', { importer: jsonImporter, indentedSyntax: true }),
    scss: generateLoaders('sass', { importer: jsonImporter }),
    stylus: generateLoaders('stylus'),
    styl: generateLoaders('stylus')
  }
```

But the json file is never transformed by the importer.

I always end up seeing the following error:

```
Module build failed:
{
^
      Invalid CSS after "{": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "{"
```

Where should I modify the build scripts to add this importer properly?

Comment: Have you by any chance found a solution within the year since this was posted?